# Flink: Table API copy operators in execution plan

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I use Flink 1.2.0 Table API for processing some streaming data. Following is my code:

```scala
val dataTable = myDataStream
// table A
val tableA = dataTable
  .window(Tumble over 5.minutes on 'rowtime as 'w)
  .groupBy("w, group1, group2")
  .select("w.start as time, group1, group2, data1.sum as data1, data2.sum as data2")
tableEnv.registerTable("tableA", tableA)
// table A sink
tableA.writeToSink(sinkTableA)
//...
// I shoul get some other outputs from TableA output
//...
val dataTable = tableEnv.ingest("tableA")
// table result1
val result1 = dataTable
 .window(Tumble over 5.minutes on 'rowtime as 'w)
 .groupBy("w, group1")
 .select("w.start as time, group1, data1.sum as data1")
// result1 sink
result2.writeToSink(sinkResult1)
// table result2
val result2 = dataTable
 .window(Tumble over 5.minutes on 'rowtime as 'w)
 .groupBy("w, group2")
 .select("w.start as time, group2, data2.sum as data1")
// result2 sink
result2.writeToSink(sinkResult2)
```

I wait to get this tree in the flink execution plan.
Same as I have for Flink Streaming in my other Flink jobs.

```
DataStream_Operators -> TableA_Operators -> TableA_Sink
                                        |-> Result1_Operators -> Result1_Sink
                                        |-> Result2_Operators -> Result2_Sink
```

But, I get this with 3 copies of same opertoprs for TableA !

```
DataStream_Operators -> TableA_Operators -> TableA_Sink
                   |-> Copy_of_TableA_Operators -> Result1_Operators -> Result1_Sink
                   |-> Copy_of_TableA_Operators -> Result2_Operators -> Result2_Sink
```

I have bad performance with big input data for this job in result.

How I can fix this and get optimal execution plan ?

I undestand, what the Flink Table API and SQL are experimental features and
maybe it's will fixed in next versions.

Answer (score 0):

At the current state, the Table API translates the whole query whenever you convert a `Table` into a `DataSet` or `DataStream` or write it to a `TableSink`. In your program, you call three times `writeToSink` which means that the each time the complete query is translated.

But what is the complete query? There are all Table API operators that have been applied on a `Table`. When you register a `Table` in the `TableEnvironment` it is basically registered as a view, i.e., only its definition (all the operators that define the Table) are registered. Therefore, these operators are translated again when you call `writeToSink` the second and third time.

You can solve this issue if you translate `tableA` into a `DataStream` and register the `DataStream` in the `TableEnvironment` instead for registering it as a `Table`. This would look as follows:

```
val tableA = ...
val streamA = tableA.toDataStream[X] // X should be a case class for rows of tableA
val tableEnv.registerDataStream("tableA", streamA)

tableEnv.ingest("tableA").writeToSink(sinkTableA) // emit tableA by ingesting the registered DataStream
```

I know, this is not very convenient but at the moment the only way to avoid repeated translation of a Table.

Comment: I cannot use case class for `TableA` results, when translate it to `DataStream` because group and select fields is configurability from config file in my job. This is one of cause, why I use the Flink Table API, not Flink Streaming, where I can use case classes for input and output data. So, I should use `Row` class for DataStream translation. But, I cannot use `Row` for next select for `resul1` and `resul2` (group and select fields is configurability there too) !

Comment: If I use `Row` with `val resultStream = result.toDataStream[Row]; tableEnv.registerDataStream("TableA", resultStream)` for `resul1` select got error: `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Cannot resolve [group1] given input [f0, f1, f2, f3, f4]`. I tried to use `Row` with fileds list `tableEnv.registerDataStream("TableA", resultStream, fields)` and got error `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Source of type Row(f0: Timestamp, f1: String, f2: String, f3: Long, f4: Long) cannot be converted into Table.`.